# Example for $\|f_n\|_p = 1$ and $\|f_n - f_m\|_p = 1$ for $m \neq n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. Let $p = [1,\infty]$. Give an example of $f_n$ such that $\|f_n\|_p = 1$ for all $n$ and $\|f_n - f_m\|_p = 1$ for $m \neq n$.

I find it hard to guarantee $\|f_n - f_m \| = 1$. Anyone has an idea how to make it happen?

Comment: It might help to first try this for the counting measure on $\mathbb N$.  Then your functions are just sequences of real numbers $\{a_k\}$ and you want $\sum_k {|a_k|^p} = 1$, etc.  It isn't hard to squeeze an example from this domain into the Lebesgue case.

Comment: Can you say more about that? That's what I tried but still have no clue.

Comment: More specifically, I'm not sure how to get $\|f_n - f_m\|=1$

Comment: First get $\|f_n - f_m\|$ to be equal to a constant $c$, which might be greater than $1$.  Then rescale $f_n$ so that $\|f_n - f_m\| = 1$, but $\|f_n\| = 1/c < 1$.  Now add a new component (common to all $f_n$ so it doesn't affect the $\|f_n - f_m\|$) to bring $\|f_n\|$ back to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct such a sequence in $L^p(1,\infty)$, say $g_n(t)=2^{-1/p}1_{(n,n+2)}(t)$ if $n=1,2$ and $g_n(t)=2^{-1/p}( 1_{(2,3)}(t) +1_{(n+1,n+2)}(t))$, and then put $f_n(t)=t^{-2/p}g_n(1/t)$.

To see that the norm of the difference is one just calculate
$$
\int_0^1 |f_n-f_m|^p = \int_0^1 t^{-2}|g_n(1/t)-g_m(1/t)|^p dt =\int_1^\infty |g_n(s)-g_m(s)|^p ds =\| g_n-g_m\|_p^p ,
$$
where we used the change of variables $s=1/t$.

Comment: I feel this function only guarantees $\|f_n\|_p = 1$ but not $\|f_n - f_m\| = 1$. Can you give some further explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @jane: I've put the argument for the norm of the difference, is it clear?

Comment: But isn't $\|g_n - g_m\|_p^p = 2$?

Comment: $|g_n - g_m| = 2^{-1/p}1_{[n,n+2]\cup[m,m+2]}$. So $\|g_n-g_m\|_p^p = 1/2 * 4 = 2$

Comment: @jane: You're right, I've (hopefully) corrected the mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Given $p=\infty$, consider

$$f_n = 1_{\{\frac{1}{2^{n}}<x\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\}}$$

Comment: You cannot let $p = \infty$. Need to find $f_n$ that works for a given $p$. sorry :(